# Python change the working directory for an exe opened with startfile

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, executable, working-directory

In python i'm using the os.startfile command to start a windows executable that does especific stuff in its own folder, the python code is running from another folder, so when I start the file, it starts in the python script's working directory, but it has to start in its own directory. I've tried to use os.chdir(path) to change the working directory, but it fails, the file still not runs in it's own folder. I thought maybe there is a command like shortcut's "Start in" line. I've searched everywere, but not success. The only solution comes to my mind is to create a shortcut and add the "start in" line, then launch the shortcut, but that is very impractical.

Comment: Why are you using `startfile` to run a program, as opposed to say the `system` command?

Comment: I would have the same problem with os.system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `os.startfile`, for starters. Use [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html), you can then use `cwd` argument of `Popen`.

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen('command', cwd = 'directory')
```

If you really want to use [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), then the best way will be to skip `os.startfile` and call it directly with `ctypes` (or look whether it's in pywin32 somewhere).

Comment: it still executes it from the python's directory! thanks for your help but it didn't work... have you tried it? are you 100% sure this should work? because it didn't

Comment: @Saulpila: How are you checking it? And which Python version are you using?

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.2. I changed the code, and ran it, I know when the executable isn't running in place, because before making it's stuff, it creates a file... and the file is being created in the python script's folder